# Git: Find last edits from a specific user in a specific file

Tags: git, last-modified, blame

I have a project which sources are controlled with help of git.

Right now I want to find out when my teammate made last edits in a specific file. I want to find out SHA1 of commit or to see his edits as diff.

I guess I can use `git log --stat <path/to/file>` and review list of all commits where my file was changed.

Are there any quick ways to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) with a pathspec and `--author` option:

```
git log --author=your_teammate -- path/to/file
```

Comment: Wow. I've forgot to review `git help log`. Thank you. `git log --author=your_teammate -- path/to/file -n 1` does the work :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes! you can use git blame

```
git blame <file>
```

every line of that file will be shown who is the one edited the last.

Comment: If you have a file is thousands of lines long, this is a horribly tedious way to figure out what the author wants

Comment: Actually `git blame` will not help me if edits of my teammate where overwritten in later commits by another author.

Comment: @Konstantin: it seems that your question is not asking what you describe in OP :p

Answer (score 2):

I would use this line
`git log --format="%H--%ad-%an" fileName`

If you only want the last change, use this
`git log --format="%H--%ad-%an" -n 1 fileName`

If you are looking for a single specific author, pipe it through grep
`git log --format="%H--%ad-%an" fileName | grep "Author Name"`